# Incomprehension of the while() loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am writing a code that enables the user to determine the profit from a sandwich selling business. And yet, I am facing problems using the while().

```
int sandwichtype=1;

cout << "Enter the type of sandwich" << endl
     << "Input 1 for cheese, 2 for veggie, 3 for customed" << endl << endl
     << "Sandwich type: ";

while (sandwichtype > 0 && sandwichtype < 4)
cin >> sandwichtype;
```

What I want is to limit the user from inputting any number other from 1, 2, or 3. And yet, when I compile, the compiler does the opposite. Why is that, and what is the solution?

Comment: Suppose you were told:  `while (you found the right answer) { solve the problem again }`. Wouldn't that seem wrong? Shouldn't it be `while (your answer was wrong) { try try again }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
int sandwichtype;

do
{
    cout << "Enter the type of sandwich" << endl
         << "Input 1 for cheese, 2 for veggie, 3 for customed" << endl << endl
         << "Sandwich type: ";
    cin >> sandwichtype;
} while ( sandwichtype < 1 || sandwichtype > 3 );
```

As for your while statement

```
while (sandwichtype > 0 && sandwichtype < 4)
cin >> sandwichtype;
```

when it iterates when the user enters a valid selection and stops iterations when the user enters an invalid selection.

Also you should check that the user did not interrupt the input. For example

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter the type of sandwich" << endl
         << "Input 1 for cheese, 2 for veggie, 3 for customed" << endl << endl
         << "Sandwich type: ";

    sandwichtype = 0;
} while ( cin >> sandwichtype && ( sandwichtype < 1 || sandwichtype > 3 ) );


if ( sandwichtype == 0 ) cout << "Oops! The user does not want to contact.";
```

Answer (score 2):

The while loop repeats as long as its expression (`(sandwichtype > 0 && sandwichtype < 4)`) evaluates to `True`.

This means, that as long as the values are `>0` and `<4` it will re-read data from the user.
Only when the user entered a value outside this range (which by your definition is an invalid data), the while-loop will stop and the program will continue (and process the invalid data).

Answer (score 2):

You have the while condition inverted - you want to print that message if user did not enter the valid number - which is any number not in interval <1,3>.

So you have to negate your condition:

```
while (!(sandwichtype > 0 && sandwichtype < 4))
```

And it may be rewritten to possibly easier to read

```
while (sandwichtype < 1 || sandwichtype > 3)
```

Last but not least, I would suggest to embrace the whole while block and indent it.

```
int sandwichtype = 0;
cin >> sandwichtype;
while (sandwichtype < 1 || sandwichtype > 3)
{   
    cout << "Enter the type of sandwich" << endl
        << "Input 1 for cheese, 2 for veggie, 3 for customed" << endl << endl
        << "Sandwich type: ";

    cin >> sandwichtype;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int sandwichtype=0;

while (sandwichtype < 1 || sandwichtype > 3) {
    cout << "Enter the type of sandwich" << endl
         << "Input 1 for cheese, 2 for veggie, 3 for customed" << endl << endl
         << "Sandwich type: ";
    cin >> sandwichtype;
}
```